# increasing the width of dropdownList

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I want to adjust the width of DropDownList control in flex 4. I could do it by editing the skinclass and setting the PopupAnchor's Property "popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth" to false, but in my application I have to do it using actionscript.

Comment: What constrains in particular you have to use ActionScript only with DropDownList? Why can't you apply skin with `setStyle()` method? Please provide us more details about your project and maybe some code snippets to understand your problem.

Comment: I couldn't access the "popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth" property through setStyle().i gave the answer. please verify and post your comments. thanks alot constantiner!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks a lot  for all responders. here i give the code which is used to clip the width of the dropdown.

package
{
    import spark.components.DropDownList;
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import spark.components.PopUpAnchor;
    import mx.collections.IList;
    import spark.components.ComboBox;

```
public class customDDList extends DropDownList
{   
    [SkinPart(popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth)]  
    public var popUp:PopUpAnchor ; 
    public function customDDList():void
    {
        super();
    }
    override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void 
    {    
        super.partAdded(partName, instance);   
                     if (partName == "popUp")   
        {
            instance.popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth = false;

        }

    }
    public override function set dataProvider(value:IList):void
    {
        super.dataProvider = value;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `typicalItem` property of the `DropDownList` to the currently selected item.

From [Flex Examples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/01/21/resizing-a-spark-dropdownlist-control-to-match-the-currently-selected-item-in-flex-4/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/01/21/resizing-a-spark-dropdownlist-control-to-match-the-currently-selected-item-in-flex-4/ -->
<s:Application name="Spark_DropDownList_typicalItem_test"
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:DropDownList id="cb"
                    labelField="name"
                    typicalItem="{cb.selectedItem}"
                    requireSelection="true"
                    left="20" top="20">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:Object name="Baltimore Orioles" abbr="BAL" />
                <fx:Object name="Boston Red Sox" abbr="BOS" />
                <fx:Object name="Chicago White Sox" abbr="CWS" />
                <fx:Object name="Cleveland Indians" abbr="CLE" />
                <fx:Object name="Detroit Tigers" abbr="DET" />
                <fx:Object name="Kansas City Royals" abbr="KC" />
                <fx:Object name="Los Angeles Angels of Anaheim" abbr="LAA" />
                <fx:Object name="Minnesota Twins" abbr="MIN" />
                <fx:Object name="New York Yankees" abbr="NYY" />
                <fx:Object name="Oakland Athletics" abbr="OAK" />
                <fx:Object name="Seattle Mariners" abbr="SEA" />
                <fx:Object name="Tampa Bay Devil Rays" abbr="TB" />
                <fx:Object name="Texas Rangers" abbr="TEX" />
                <fx:Object name="Toronto Blue Jays" abbr="TOR" />
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:DropDownList>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Jason, i have learnt a new concept from your code.but in case i have to write the custom component.and also i give the answer

Answer (score 0):

You might as well create another skin for the DropDownList component and set the `popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth` property to `false` on the `PopUpAnchor` skin part:

```
    <s:PopUpAnchor id="popUp"  
    displayPopUp.normal="false" displayPopUp.open="true" includeIn="open"
    left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" 
    itemDestructionPolicy="auto" 
    popUpPosition="below"
    popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth="false" >
```

Comment: yeah this is also good , but in my project , skins should be used. so that only i accessed the skin part through actionscript itself.